# incorrect overwriting of a json file

Tags: json, python-3.x, overwrite

I need to find a value in a file and then remove the block, but I have a trouble.

```
def fineder(filename='C:\\path\\config.json'):
    with open(filename, 'r+') as file:
        file_data = json.load(file)
        for item in file_data['inbounds'][1]['settings']['clients']:
            print(item)
            if item['id'] == 'xxxxxxxxxx':
                    for key in ['id', 'email', 'flow']:
                        item.pop(key, '')
                    if not item:  
                        file_data['inbounds'][1]['settings']['clients'].remove(item)
        file.seek(0)
        json.dump(file_data, file, indent=4)
```

After processing, an additional block is added to the end of the file, which breaks the file structure. As a result I get the following output:

```
{
    "log": {
        "loglevel": "info"
    },
    "routing": {
        "rules": [],
        "domainStrategy": "AsIs"
    },
    "inbounds": [
        {
            "port": 23,
            "tag": "ss",
            "protocol": "shadowsocks",
            "settings": {
                "method": "2022-blake3-aes-128-gcm",
                "password": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa24356475bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
                "network": "tcp,udp"
            }
        },
        {
            "port": 443,
            "protocol": "vless",
            "tag": "vless_tls",
            "settings": {
                "clients": [
                    {
                        "id": "xyxyxyxyxyxy",
                        "email": "user1@myserver",
                        "flow": "xtls-rprx-vision"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "ofofofofofofo",
                        "email": "user2@myserver",
                        "flow": "xtls-rprx-vision"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
                        "email": "user3@myserver",
                        "flow": "xtls-rprx-vision"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "hfhfhfhhfhfhfh",
                        "email": "user4@myserver",
                        "flow": "xtls-rprx-vision"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "ldldldldldld",
                        "email": "test@myserver",
                        "flow": "xtls-rprx-vision"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "assasasasasas",
                        "email": "testxtls1@myserver",
                        "flow": "xtls-rprx-vision"
                    }
                ],
                "decryption": "none",
                "fallbacks": [
                    {
                        "path": "/myverysecretpath",
                        "dest": "@vless-ws"
                    },
                    {
                        "dest": "8080"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "streamSettings": {
                "network": "tcp",
                "security": "tls",
                "tlsSettings": {
                    "alpn": [
                        "http/1.1",
                        "h2"
                    ],
                    "certificates": [
                        {
                            "certificateFile": "/myverysecretpath/file.key",
                            "keyFile": "/myverysecretpath/file.pem"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "sniffing": {
                "enabled": true,
                "destOverride": [
                    "http",
                    "tls"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "listen": "@vless-ws",
            "protocol": "vless",
            "tag": "vless_ws",
            "settings": {
                "clients": [
                    {
                        "id": "nvnvnvnvnnv",
                        "email": "user2@myserver"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "nvnvnvnnvnv",
                        "email": "test@myserver",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "cxvnvbcnbcvn",
                        "email": "testwebsocket@myserver"
                    }
                ],
                "decryption": "none"
            },
            "streamSettings": {
                "network": "ws",
                "security": "none",
                "wsSettings": {
                    "path": "/myverysecretpath"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "outbounds": [
        {
            "protocol": "freedom",
            "tag": "direct"
        },
        {
            "protocol": "blackhole",
            "tag": "block"
        }
    ]
}  }
        }
    ],
    "outbounds": [
        {
            "protocol": "freedom",
            "tag": "direct"
        },
        {
            "protocol": "blackhole",
            "tag": "block"
        }
    ]
}
```

What's funny is that when I print before writing to a file, there is nothing like that.

```
with open('C:\\path\\setting.json', 'w') as blyat:    
            blyat.seek(0)
            json.dump(file_data, blyat, indent=4)
```

I was able to get around this by opening a new file for writing. But I think it's a bad option. Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?